# How is web hosting CPU usage measured?

Tags: web-hosting, virtualhost, cpu

Among virtual hosting providers, there is usually an amount of storage and bandwidth specified in the service description (example: 50 GB storage, 1 TB bandwidth/month) but no such thing for CPU usage. However, usually a clause in the agreement says something about using resources excessively.

- How is this measured?
- What is the measurement units?
- What is being measured?
- Is this a CPU usage percentage?
- Does the peak count or the average (over a period)?
- Excessive relative to what?
- Since no measure is specified in the agreement, what can be done to avoid
  being squeezed into more expensive plans?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either specify a single host here, or ask whoever you're thinking about directly.

This isn't done the same way by all hosts, but as far as a couple of the later points, some disclose details within their technical information for how this is calculated. Others actually provide a view of the data within their control panels. If they don't, there's usually a bit of flexibility, to account for occasional spikes and such, but if you *keep* bumping up against the limits you'll be told to upgrade or move.

Comment: Well, I am trying to keep the question general because I need to understand my current host (Penguin Web) and evaluate if I am within the limits of other hosts I am considering. AFAIK, there is no way to see the usage and no metric limit at the current host.